# Can't get 'apprequests' for facebook test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created 2 test users on my app in Facebook.
I've sent gifts from one to another, but when I try to get them from facebook graph using

> apprequest (https://graph.facebook.com/{facebook id}/apprequests?access_token={app token})

I get none.

It works with regular users.

Can it be done with test users? how?

Comment: This sounds like a legitimate bug. Can you file a bug on developers.facebook.com/bugs and please include the necessary code to replicate this.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?  I had this issue and was able to solve it!

Comment: @RussellAsher No I haven't solve it. How did you?